# Declaring Pointer to Pointer in an Array causes Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault

I'm currently working on a project where I am implementing my own Threads API.

I have a function where I aim to return a pointer to a given thread that corresponds to a unique id. I have defined it as follows:

```
thread *getThread(Tid id){
    thread *want = threadsArr[id]; // threadsArr is an array that keeps track of created threads
    if (want != NULL && want->id == id){
        // free(want);
        printf("Arrived here");
        return want;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_MAX_THREADS; i++){
            want = threadsArr[i];
            if (want == NULL){
                continue;
            }
            else {
                if (want->id == id){
                    return want;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I ran gdb and it says that the line `thread *want = threadsArr[id];` is causing a Segmentation Fault.

I have initialized everything in a function as follows:

```
void
thread_init(void)
{
    int idx = 0;
    for (idx = 0; idx < THREAD_MAX_THREADS; idx++){
        threadsArr[idx] = NULL;
    }
    currunThread = (thread *)malloc(sizeof(thread));
    currunThread->id = 0;
    currunThread->status = RUNNING;
    //initialize structure pointed to by ucp to the current user context of the calling thread
    getcontext(&(currunThread->context));

    readyThreads = (queue *)malloc(sizeof(queue));
    initQ(readyThreads);

    threadsArr[currunThread->id] = currunThread;
}
```

I've used this method in previous programs before and haven't got Seg Faults, so I am wondering why its happening now??

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** If I get rid of the return statement in getThread(Tid id), I no longer receive a Sementation Fault. But if I keep it the Segmentation fault occures when I do `thread *want = threadsArr[id];`.

Comment: `threadsArr[]` seems to be a global variable, is that so?

Comment: Code is too incomplete. Please provide a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). One thing that should be done regardless is that `id` should be validated before using it as an array index. What value is it when the seg fault occurs?

Comment: Keep removing code and confirm that you get the fault. Then give us the minimum amount of code necessary to replicate the fault. There's a good chance you'll find the issue yourself in this process.

Comment: @MukulKumar yes the threadsArr is a global variable, declared as, `thread *threadsArr[THEAD_MAX_THREADS]`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If I get rid of the return statement in getThread(Tid id), I no longer receive a Sementation Fault. But if I keep it the Segmentation fault occures when I do thread *want = threadsArr[id];

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is the "id" variable is out of the scope:

```
thread *getThread(Tid id){
    if (id >= THREAD_MAX_THREADS)
        return NULL;

    thread *want = threadsArr[id];
...
```

And you have a missing ';' at the end of questionable line.

If `threadsArr` is declared as a global pointer and then malloc to an array like:

```
thread *threadsArr;

some_function()
{
    threadsArr = malloc(THREAD_MAX_THREADS * sizeof(thread *));
}
```

there is a possibility that the variable has been overwritten by some other functions, e.g. out-of-bound array write.